# Node.js DOM tree getComputedStyle alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am in Node.js and have a DOM tree. I need to be able to pick any particular element, and get ALL styles associated with it from the rest of the DOM.

Is there an HTML parser which I can reverse all inherited styles from any individual element? And if not, how could I create a function which reverses the "computed style" of any individual element in the DOM tree?

i.e. something like this:

```js
let htmlDoc = htmlParser.fromHTML(
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   * {
    color: red;
   }
   div {
    width: 500px;
   }
   .target {
    height: 20px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="background-color: black">
   <div id="tgt" class="target">some text</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
);

getStyleOf(htmlDoc.getElementById("tgt")); // "width: 500px; height: 20px; color: red;"
```

Comment: We don't do library recommendation. Note that I doubt there is any such JS library that does all the CSSOM computation that this would require anyway. I invite you to look at headless browsers instead.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. If I can't get pointed to a library, is there some way I can write my own polyfill?